# Establecer la fecha del día

Tags: java

Necesito establecer en un campo la fecha del día y que no pueda ser modificada por el usuario.

Se me ocurrió hacer una etiqueta `Fecha` y un `jTextField2` para establecer la fecha y que se vea gris este campo (osea que no se pueda modificar), pero no lo logro.

```
package elbuengusto;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;


@author jorge

public class NuevaVenta extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public NuevaVenta() {
        initComponents();

        Calendar fecha = new GregorianCalendar();
        jTextField2.setText();//***aquí queria setear la fecha actual***    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar `Date` y [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
Date fecha = new Date(); //fecha y hora actual
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); //formatear la fecha en una cadena
jTextField2.setText(sdf.format(fecha)); //setear la representacion en cadena de la fecha
```

Si necesitas un formato diferente para la fecha, puedes revisar la documentación de `SimpleDateFormat` en el vínculo indicado arriba.

Si tu `jTextField` no debe ser editable, puedes hacerlo ineditable para el usuario mediante:

```
jextField2.setEditable(false);
```

O puedes considerar utilizar un componente que no es editable como un `JLabel`.

Comment: te lo agradezco, sabes como hacer este campo no editable?

Comment: Usa un `JLabel` en lugar de un `JTextField` o actualiza el campo usando `JTextField#setEditable(false)`

Comment: Por cierto, si vas a utilizar `Calendar`, inicializalo de la siguiente manera: `Calendar calendar = Calendar.getCalendar()` en lugar de utilizar `GregorianCalendar`, así tu código es independiente de los tipos de calendario y delegas ese trabajo a la JVM.

Comment: Entendido @Luiggi Mendoza, gracias por los consejos, ya solucione todo.